# Declare arrays for 3 float arrays

Tags: arrays, c

How to declare variables for the  3  parameters associated with sampling the x-axis and give them values?  How to declare arrays for  3  float arrays: x[], y[], and z[]?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your own attempt, together with a description of the problems you have with it. Lastly, please don't span unrelated tag (like the `latex` tag you added).

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about [arrays usage](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-in-c-cpp/) in C. Declaring array of floats is same as declaring it for any other type. You can declare `float` arrays like this:

```c
    float x[] = {3.544, 5.544, 6.544, 6.544};
    float y[] = {4.223, 21.12, 43.1, 4.3};
    float z[] = {5.12, 34.5, 12.2, 3.5};
```

If you want to dynamically allocate it, you might want to use [malloc](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/) for dynamic allocation.